# Spark / Cashier / Paddle - Paddle API error 'settings for seller 12345 not found' occurred

Tags: laravel, laravel-spark, paddle

Paddle Billing. Spark 5. Laravel 10. A seemingly legal and valid call to the /pricing-preview endpoint ends with settings for [seller id] not found.

I'm sending these:

```
  "items" => array:2 [▼
    0 => array:2 [▼
      "price_id" => "pri_01hr72xx"
      "quantity" => 1
    ]
    1 => array:2 [▼
      "price_id" => "pri_01hr72zz"
      "quantity" => 1
    ]
  ]
  "customer_ip_address" => "127.0.0.1"
```

Sandbox environment set, sandbox api url being used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this issue as well. I had to save the Checkout Settings once and then it showed the billing page.